# Gerar CSV em Python a partir de um txt

Tags: python, csv, txt

Eu tentando executar o código:

```
import csv

listaG = []
arquivoSaida = 'teste.csv'

with open('Arquivos_avanco.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='-', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        listaG.append([','.join(row)])
        #print (','.join(row))

with open(arquivoSaida, 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Marca', 'Modelo', 'Ano'])
    for i in listaG:
        spamwriter.writerow(i)
```

Erro retornado:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Johann
>   Herbert\Desktop\python_curso\teste.py", line 50, in 
>       spamwriter.writerow(['Marca', 'Modelo', 'Ano'])
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Sou iniciante na linguagem

Comment: E você não precisa abrir um arquivo, ler todo o conteúdo em uma lista para depois gravá-la em outro arquivo; você pode escrever a medida que vai lendo, no mesmo laço de repetição

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Johann,

O que está acontecendo é o parametro que você está colocando no construtor do CSV.

```
with open(arquivoSaida, 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Marca', 'Modelo', 'Ano'])
    for i in listaG:
        spamwriter.writerow(i)
```

No trecho acima o `wb` significa que você está gravando no arquivo (w) e que está escrevendo no modo binário (b), por isso, há este erro de gravar.

Para poder gravar somete o texto basta colocar na mesma liga somente o 'w' e se caso você deseja ir colocando em sequência, coloque a letra 'a' que será referenciada para `append` e não irá sobreescrever as informações anteriores.

```
with open(arquivoSaida, 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Marca', 'Modelo', 'Ano'])
```

Referência: [CSV Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)